# Is there a way to separate and clone an image area with cv2?

Tags: python, computer-vision, real-time, opencv

I know the title isn't very clear but its kinda a complicated idea and I don't have the slightest clue how else to explain it. If you can think of a better title please, please, **please** , tell me and ill edit the title.

My problem is this: One of my close coder pals challenged me to re-create [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1b5aiTrGzY) Image to Image translation example. There are a few catches though.

1. I cant use any pre-trained neural networks
2. I have to make it run realtime (use webcam)

So far I have made it up to having the face swapped but i need to make it go back on to the non webcam image but there is an issue. to do that I have to re-build and warp the whole image around that image including filling the background behind the face that isn't included in the the original source image. I have tried to use impainting but on some occasions it takes part of the hair and neck and merges it into the background just creating a mess of skin and hair colors. I have also tried expanding my mask on the `cv2` impainting function but that results in a big background color square that also looks terrible. I assume the best solution would be to segment off the biggest area around the head with some sort of segmenting algorithm, then clone part of that area to preserve the background texture instead of creating a new bad texture and placing that cloned area inside the mask. This all has to be done in realtime.

In the end I need to copy the person in `img1`, then **remove** them (part im stuck on). then take the facial landmarks from `img2` and map those landmarks onto `img1`'s clone's face, then add the re-mapped `img1` back onto the `img1` background. I know i cant communicate these ideas as clearly as someone more qualified as i am in 8th grade so if any clarification is required please ask.

Comment: So, in essence, you need to perform face translation between a predefined image and the live feed from the webcam in real-time without using any neural networks. The problem with using facial landmarks is that they do not cover the whole face so the hair and remaining portion would remain the same. Another problem can be orientation, if the orientation of the faces is not the same then the proper mapping will be very difficult. If these are not an issue then we can try to extract the mask and resize it accordingly and paste it on to the feed.

Comment: How would I go about creating a landmark map **with** the hair? also I **can** use neural networks i just cant use pre trained ones, I have to train my own

Comment: I feel you will have to go for GAN's and facial landmarks won't work well. Suppose the person in the live feed opens his mouth or closes his eye and the picture you have doesn't have these capabilities then it would just be a still head on a body.

Comment: Ok I'll look into gans more, i've known about them but I don't have particularly advanced hardware and didn't want to mess with the very compacted code of some of the gans to make it realtime.